# Null value gotten from a f:param inside a h:selectOneMenu in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

i tried to pass a value throught a f:param inside a h:selectOneMenu like shown in the following code :

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{jbpmAPIUtil.procNdNameSelectedValue}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{jbpmAPIUtil.procnodes}" var="pn"
                                                itemLabel="#{pn.getName()}" itemValue="#{pn.getId()}" />
                                            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{jbpmAPIUtil.OnONeMenuProcNdSelChgeHndler}" />
                                            <f:param value="${msntoc.getWorkitemid()}" name="msntocwiid"/>                                          
                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

i ve even changed the value of the f:param to a String but always got null when trying to get that value in the handler :

```
public static void OnONeMenuProcNdSelChgeHndler(AjaxBehaviorEvent vce){

        String msntocwiid = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap()
                .get("msntocwiid");


        System.out.println("procNdNameSelectedValue : "+procNdNameSelectedValue+" msntocwiid :"+msntocwiid);



    }
```

Doesn't the selectOneMenu support the f:param ? is there another way to pass a value instead ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: Is there a typo of `getWorkitemid` => `getWorkitemId` and there is a reason using $ sign ?

Comment: no and $ is from the EL and as i mentionned above, i ve tested the param value with a string and it didn't work neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:param>` child to add a request parameter is only supported in `UICommand` components (e.g. `<h:commandLink>`, `<h:commandButton>`, etc). It's not supported in `UIInput` components.

In *your particular case* you've 2 options to achieve the concrete functional requirement anyway:

1. Pass it as listener method argument instead.

   ```
   <h:selectOneMenu ...>
       ...
       <f:ajax ... listener="#{jbpmAPIUtil.OnONeMenuProcNdSelChgeHndler(msntoc.workitemid)}" />
   </h:selectOneMenu>
   ```

   with

   ```
   public void OnONeMenuProcNdSelChgeHndler(String msntocwiid) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   ---
2. Or, if you really need to have a hand at `AjaxBehaviorEvent` for some unclear reason, then evaluate it programmatically.

   ```
   public void OnONeMenuProcNdSelChgeHndler(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
       String msntocwiid = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{msntoc.workitemid}", String.class);
       // ...
   }
   ```

   ---

You've by the way terrible naming conventions. I strongly recommend to read the [official resource](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) on the subject to make it yourself, your future maintainers and us more happy.